# How to display results on click of button after selecting items from spinner

Tags: android, android-layout

I have written a code to roll dice. When user clicks on  1 dice,it should give number between 1 and 6 .When user clicks on 2 dice it should generate numbers between 2 and 12.I used spinner and image button.But I don't know where to place the logic for dice 1 and dice 2 to generate numbers in that range .

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 

AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {


private ImageButton  btnroll;
private Spinner spinner;
private static final String[] paths = {"1 dice", " 2 dice"}

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,paths);

  adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    btnroll= findViewById(R.id.btnRoll);

}
     public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
   switch (position) {
        case 0:


        case 1:


        case 2:


    }
}
```

I know the code  to display results of image button is something like this.But  don't know how to connect this with spinner. The sample onclick button code is just for dice 1.Please help

```
   btnroll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int result = rand.nextInt( (1 - 6) + 1) + 1;
    final int random = new Random().nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),String.valueOf(result),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


}
     })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int max, min;
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    switch (position) {
       case 0:
            break;
       case 1:
            min = 1;
            max = 6;
            break;
       case 2:
            min = 2;
            max = 12;
            break;
      }
}
```

Or if no need using max/min outside,

```
btnroll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int index = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
        if (index == 0) {
            return;
        }
        int min = index * 1;
        int max = index * 6;
        Random rand = new Random();
        final int random = new Random().nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),String.valueOf(result),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring the result variable in btnroll as class variable. This way you can access the value outside. Hope it helps.